# JDA override method is grayed out

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am trying to create a bot that checks if a user attempts to enter a new voice channel, but when trying to override the onVoiceChannelUpdate method, it stays grayed out and gives me error that I don't have the parameters class.

This is the code I have for this method:

```
@Override
public void onVoiceChannelUpdate(VoiceChannelUpdateEvent event) {
    User user = event.getUser();
    VoiceChannel oldVoiceChannel = event.getOldVoiceChannel();
    VoiceChannel newVoiceChannel = event.getNewVoiceChannel();
    if (checkUserVoiceChannelRequest(user, oldVoiceChannel)) {
        System.out.println(user.getName() + " has left the voice channel " + oldVoiceChannel.getName() + " and entered " + newVoiceChannel.getName() + ".");
    }
}
```

I tried multiple ways of doing it, but all the methods have the exact same problem. I have some methods from before that check messages and all that and they work, but for any of the other methods that I use, the parameter class is not existent.

Errors showing:
[image]

[image]

Tried with onGuildVoiceUpdate method also, but it has the same issue:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the error? It is hard to tell from your description what you mean.

Comment: @Minn I added some pictures, maybe this might help?

Comment: Is your class extending ListenerAdapter, and which version of JDA are you using?

Comment: @Minn yes, it is. I have other methods that work just fine. Also, I am using the version 5.0.0-alpha.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try

```java
public class Test extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onGuildVoiceUpdate(GuildVoiceUpdateEvent event) {
        AudioChannel oldChannel = event.getChannelLeft();
        AudioChannel newChannel = event.getChannelJoined();
    }
}
```

Using JDA 5.0.0-beta.2.

If that does not work it might be an issue with your IDE so try to invalidate your cache.

Comment: invalidating the cache worked. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`GuildVoiceUpdateEvent`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/guild/voice/GuildVoiceUpdateEvent.html) instead.

```java
@Override
public void onGuildVoiceUpdate(GuildVoiceUpdateEvent event) {
    AudioChannel oldChannel = event.getChannelLeft();
    AudioChannel newChannel = event.getChannelJoined();
    ...
}
```

Comment: This also doesn't work. It is the same error showing. I'll edit to add the picture as well –